# Configure nginx to proxy by header?

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, http-proxy

Basically, my question is how do I proxy requests by header using nginx? So for example,

- if the header has a cookie, then it needs to pass through
- but if it has no header, then it needs to redirect to a login page
- the exception is if a "special" admin-defined header is set. If that header exists, then pass it through regardless of the cookies.

How can I do this with nginx? Or should I be using something else? (It's for oauth2 if that matters.)

I have seen this: http://sites.psu.edu/jasonheffner/2015/06/19/nginx-use-different-backend-based-on-http-header/ however, I'm not sure yet if that's what I need.

Update: it looks like the link referenced above can give me the first two requirements. For example, the below probably works; however, it's not clear how I would handle the third requirement.

So how can I make this also allow requests with another header defined? Is it possible to define `proxy_pass` based on the outcome of a conditional?

```
map $http_cookie $redirect {
 default "loginpage"; # no cookie go to login page
 *       "";                # otherwise pass thru     
}

server {
 location / {
      proxy_pass http://server/$redirect;
 }
}
```

Comment: If you use nginx only as a load balancer, you can use HAProxy to easily achieve these